# the Hardware Back Button does not work with Ionic and Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, hardware, back

I haven't been able to get it to work for a few weeks now the Hardware Back Button.
currently when we click back button the app is closed.

[ionic info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbKor.png)

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(-1, () => {
  console.log("test")      
});
```

Comment: where did you put this line of code? and are you sure it doesn't log before closing the app? because your code shouldn't stop it from closing the app.

Comment: I put this line in " this.platform.ready().then(async () => {"

Comment: That's because the priority is set to -1. Try to set it to higher number.

Comment: I also tested with 10 and 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';
    App.addListener('backButton', ({ canGoBack }) => {
     console.log(canGoBack);
      if(canGoBack){
       window.history.back();
       } else {
        App.exitApp();
       }
     });
```

watch out, on android :

```java
registerPlugin(com.capacitorjs.plugins.app.AppPlugin.class);
```

Comment: Please explain where to add the registrePlugin code